# Extjs - Stop client to append any "id" with Model instance before sending it to server via REST

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Client(Browser) is automatically appending "id" in my JSON which I am sending to server. 
Here is my model with proxy:

```
fields: ['id','title','body'],

    idProperty: 'id',  // this is the default value (for clarity)

    // clientIdProperty: 'cliendID',

     identifier: 'sequential', // to generate -1, -2 etc on the client

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        //appendId: false,
        limitParam:"",
        filterParam: "",
        startParam:'',
        pageParam:'',
        url:'http://localhost:3000/posts',

        headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json" },     

        reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty:'posts'

        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }

    }
```

When I create a model object to send data to server via Rest, Rest fill the 'id' field with (NameOfMymodel-number).

This is code to create and send model object to server via Rest:

```
var UserStore = Ext.getStore('peopleStore');
var user = Ext.create('ThemeApp.model.peopleModel',{'title': "Test", 'body': "Testing" });
user.save(); //POST /users
UserStore.load();
```

Is there any way to stop extjs from appending such id with my data?

This is a similar kind of problem but not what I am looking.
[how do i prevent an extjs model/proxy from saving the empty primary id on create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084688/how-do-i-prevent-an-extjs-model-proxy-from-saving-the-empty-primary-id-on-create)

Comment: [Is there any way to disable “idProperty” of Model in Extjs?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562263/is-there-any-way-to-disable-idproperty-of-model-in-extjs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set persist to false and that's it

```
Ext.define('ThemeApp.model.peopleModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [ {name: 'id', type: 'int', persist: false},
                  {name: 'xyz', type: 'auto'}]
    }
```

The 'idProperty' default value is 'id', so simply set persist: false for id property in your model.
credits: ajokon (Pointed this in comments by referring to another stackoverflow question)